# php , read file code problem

Tags: php, file, preg-match

I was using this piece of php code for a site.
Now its old and I recently had a few attacks. Script was used for to include another file from someplace else and send spam. Obviously this makes my script as spam sender.

for the content

```
$htm = ".htm";
$pid = "$details$htm";
function show_details($pid)
{
if (!preg_match("/http/", $pid)) {
require($pid);
} else {
   die;
}
}
```

and for the title, desc , keywords etc..

```
$txt = ".txt";
$title = "$details$txt";
function show_title($title)
{
if (!preg_match("/http/", $title)) {
if (file_exists($title)) {
require($title);
} else {
   die;
}
}
}
```

and a display.php file with

```
print '
<!-- CONTENT -->
';
show_details("$pid");
print '
```

by this code ı was able to call any content by "/display.php?details=mycontentpage"

mycontentpage.htm
mycontentpage.txt

.............

Now this code has to be re-coded .. I can not change the construction as the site is just too big.
So I guess I just have to stick to this..

Can anyone help ? Any comments ?

Comment: If they could include to a file somewhere, your entire site is compromised. Even if you patch this, there could be thousands of back door spots they've opened up. Take this seriously. ---- That being said, your description of what you're trying to do was so confusingly worded that I can't understand what your problem actually was.

Answer (score 0):

To make scripts like this more secure, you have to ensure register_globals is set to OFF. This means you'll have to add a line like:

`php_flag register_globals off`

...To .htaccess. Then, declare all your user variables the first time you use them like:

`$details = $_GET['details']`

...Which assigns the data from the URI piece "details" to the PHP variable $details.

I can very much see how your attackers were able to get in via your code and register_globals set to on -- they'd need to merely create a .htm file with PHP code in it that reassigns other variables, include it, then viola.

For more info, see:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: You probably also want some class that sanitizes the contents of the .htm and .txt files if you allow users to create these -- at minimum, run it through htmlentities(); -- see: http://ca2.php.net/htmlentities

Comment: thanks... but the thing is I can not change the code for all the website, its just too large. We are already preparing a new site.
I need t find a temporarly solution for this.
if there is "http" at the get address (which means its out of this site), die.. else run.. But I need to also include "ftp", "//", "/",":" .. If I can also include these, should buy me enought time. ANY ideas ?

Comment: I don't see how size has anything to do with it (Unless you're doing something like replicating the above code on every page -- if so, you're doing it wrong...); ultimately, by declaring your variables, you don't change how the code functions at all -- you just use them in a slightly more secure fashion. 

It might be worthwhile using is_file(); instead of preg_match, if only in the latter precludes you from naming files "http" or any derivatives of that. Maybe try something to the extent of:
if( is_file( $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . "/my_images/abc.jpg")){}